# What is the implementation of hinge loss in Tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, svm, deep-learning, tensorflow

$L_i$ is the hinge loss here. $y_i$ the correct class. Rest is self explanatory

from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinge_loss#Extensions) i get:

Weston and Watkins:
$L_i = \sum_{j\neq y_i} \max(0, w_j^T x_i - w_{y_i}^T x_i + 1)$

Crammer and Singer:
$L_i =  \max(0, max_{j\neq y_i}(w_j^T x_i) - w_{y_i}^T x_i + 1)$

and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/ops/losses/losses_impl.py#L331) is the implementation of hinge loss from tensorflow:

```
if labels is None:
    raise ValueError("labels must not be None.")


if logits is None:
    raise ValueError("logits must not be None.")
with ops.name_scope(scope, "hinge_loss", (logits, labels, weights)) as scope:
    logits = math_ops.to_float(logits)
    labels = math_ops.to_float(labels)
    logits.get_shape().assert_is_compatible_with(labels.get_shape())
    # We first need to convert binary labels to -1/1 labels (as floats).
    all_ones = array_ops.ones_like(labels)
    labels = math_ops.subtract(2 * labels, all_ones)
    losses = nn_ops.relu(
        math_ops.subtract(all_ones, math_ops.multiply(labels, logits)))
    return compute_weighted_loss(
        losses, weights, scope, loss_collection, reduction=reduction)
```

I am not able to reconcile this implementation to any of the definitions given above. What is the implementation of hinge loss in the Tensorflow?

Please note that `compute_weighted_loss` is just the weighted average of all the elements. weights is a parameter to the functions which is generally, and at default, a tensor of all ones

Comment: Could you add hyperlink references to the Weston-Clarke and Crammer-Singer definitions? Thank you.

Comment: made the link available @Jim

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the very first version of hinge loss on the [Wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinge_loss)

That first version, for reference:

$\ell(y) = \text{max}(0, 1 - t \cdot y)$

This assumes your labels are in a $\pm1$ binary, per the TensorFlow code you linked to and the Wiki page. The correspondence between the equation above and the code is:

- $t$ is `labels = math_ops.subtract(2 * labels, all_ones)`, which assumes `labels` comes in as a tensor with values of  $[0,1]$
- $y$ is the direct output of your model (which is why they're referred to as the `logits`)
- $1 - t \cdot y$ is captured by `math_ops.subtract(all_ones, math_ops.multiply(labels, logits))`

Comment: please refer to the specific multinomial extension i have linked to in the recent edit in question. what you are referring to is a binary classification problem formulation